# C: while loop using floating point never terminates

Tags: c, floating-point, precision

By executing this code:

```
float f = 1.0;
while (f != 0.0) {
    f = f - 0.1;
    printf("%.1f\n", f);
}
```

It is expected that it would run 10 times and stop, but what turns out is that it inevitably goes into stack overflow. The same happens even if I change the while loop such that f goes to any other value below 1.0;

Anyone care to explain?

Comment: Are you sure that you have stack overflow rather than infinite loop?

Answer (score 3):

It's dangerous to compare floats for equality/non-equality.  `float` numbers are imprecise by nature because there are not enough bits to represent continuous nature of the `float` number.

Any time you compare `float`s, you should be comparing that the `float`s are within certain range of each other.  For example:

```
while ((f - 0.0) > 0.00001)
```

Comment: I read a similar post in VBA where the negative problem was solved with squaring where they do: `if ((f*f) > 0.00001) /*not equal*/`

Comment: ...without which you should write `while (((f - 0.0) > 0.00001 || ((f - 0.0) < -0.00001)`

Comment: Comparing a _floating point_ to a constant takes the _floating_ out of floating point. A _relative_ compare more useful.

Answer (score 2):

Why did code loop forever?

Typical `float` can represent about 2<sup>32</sup> numbers exactly,  `0.1` is not one of them.  So code is more like.

```
float f = 1.0;
while (f != 0.0) {
  f = f - a_number_close_to_one_tenth;
  printf("%.1f\n", f);
}
```

The repeated subtractions "miss" 0.0.

---

Instead use `>=` and code will iterate the expected number of times (or maybe once more).  Use a higher precision print to see why.

```
float f = 1.0;
while (f >= 0.0) {
  f = f - a_number_close_to_one_tenth;
  printf("%.17e\n", f);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a floating point issue. Try `>` instead of `!=`

```
float f = 1.0;
while (f > 0.0) {
    f = f - 0.1;
    printf("%.1f\n", f);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Loops should better never be done on floating points.
It's even required by some coding standards like rule FLP30-C at https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/FLP30-C.+Do+not+use+floating-point+variables+as+loop+counters